# Simple Blackjack Game - CLI: The code is complete, but nothing happens

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I think there is something wrong with my code, but I can't figure it out. I actually copied the code from a book, but it is disordered and I tried to order the code in a way that seems reasonable. But whenever I run the program, it just doesn't work. There are no error messages, and the program runs, but nothing happens.

I'm still new to programming, and I want to learn why am I experiencing this, and how may I solve this problem?

```
import random

# Card Class
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return " of ".join((self.value, self.suit))

# Deck class
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(s, v) for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds"]
        for v in ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]]

    def shuffle(self):
        if len(self.cards) > 1:
            random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self):
        if len(self.cards) > 1:
            return self.cards.pop(0)

# Hand Class
class Hand:
    def __init__(self, dealer=False):
        self.dealer = dealer
        self.cards = []
        self.value = 0

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def calculate_value(self):
        self.value = 0
        has_ace = False
        for card in self.cards:
            if card.value.isnumeric():
                self.value += int(card.value)
            else:
                if card.value == "A":
                    has_ace = True
                    self.value += 11
                else:
                    self.value += 10

        if has_ace and self.value > 21:
            self.value -= 10

    def get_value(self):
        self.calculate_value()
        return self.value

    def display(self):
        if self.dealer:
            print("hidden")
            print(self.cards[1])
        else:
            for card in self.cards:
                print(card)
            print("Value: ", self.get_value())


# Game class and main loop
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        playing = True

        while playing:
            self.deck = Deck()
            self.deck.shuffle()

            self.player_hand = Hand()
            self.dealer_hand = Hand(dealer=True)

            for i in range(2):
                self.player_hand.add_card(self.deck.deal())
                self.dealer_hand.add_card(self.deck.deal())

            print("Your hand is:")
            self.player_hand.display()
            print()
            print("Dealer's hand is:")
            self.dealer_hand.display()


        game_over = False

        while not game_over:
            player_has_blackjack, dealer_has_blackjack = self.check_for_blackjack()

            def check_for_blackjack(self):
                player = False
                dealer = False
                if self.player_hand.get_value() == 21:
                    player = True
                if self.dealer_hand.get_value == 21:
                    dealer = True

                return player, dealer

            if player_has_blackjack or dealer_has_blackjack:
                game_over = True
                self.show_blackjack_results(player_has_blackjack, dealer_has_blackjack)
                continue

                def show_blackjack_results(self, player_has_blackjack, dealer_has_blackjack):
                    if player_has_blackjack and dealer_has_blackjack:
                        print("Both players have blackjack! Draw!")

                    elif player_has_blackjack:
                        print('You have blackjack! You win!')

                    elif dealer_has_blackjack:
                        print("Dealer has blackjack! Dealer wins!")

        choice = input("Please choose [Hit / Stick] ").lower()
        while choice not in ("h", "s", "hit", "stick"):
            choice = input("Please choose [Hit / Stick] ").lower()

            if choice in ["hit", "h"]:
                self.player_hand.add_card(self.deck.deal())
                self.player_hand.display()

            def player_is_over(self):
                return self.playe_hand.get_value() > 21

            if self.player_is_over():
                print("You have lost!")
                has_won = True

            else:
                print("Final Results")
                print("Your hand:", self.player_hand.get_value())
                print("Dealer's hand:", self.dealer_hand.get_value())

                if self.player_hand.get_value > self.dealer_hand.get_value():
                    print("You Win!")
                else:
                    print("Dealer Wins!")
                    has_won = True

            again = input("Play again? [Y/N] ")
            while again.lower() not in ["y", "n"]:
                again = input("Play again? [Y/N] ")
                if again.lower() == "n":
                    print("Thanks for playing!")
                    playing = False
                else:
                    has_won = False

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                game = Game()
```

Comment: It's a simple indentation bug, those last 2 lines are part of `Game`.  They shouldn't be - the `if __name__ == "__main__":` must be up against the very left side (i.e: not indented at all), and the `game = Game()` just under that, indented 1-place.

Comment: Oh, I see. But now when I try to run the program, it keeps looping to infinity.

Comment: On second thought, I think the program is designed to run this way (continue to loop until a winner is decided.). Or I may be wrong, am I @Kingsley?

Comment: Is it intentional to have all the functions defined within the loops? Doesn't this make it more difficult to read/understand?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been thinking too, @Ken. This is actually my first time (I'm still a beginner) seeing a function inside a while loop, and it's difficult to keep track. But maybe I'll see more of this in the future.